# way to recognize AudioTrack stopped

Tags: android

Hallo,
I'm using AudioTrack

```
audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
     sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
     AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, numSamples,
     AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
audioTrack.write(generatedSnd, 0, numSamples) ;
audioTrack.play();
```

is there a way to recognize if audioTrack have stopped?

```
while(audioTrack.getPlayState() == AudioTrack.PLAYSTATE_PLAYING){
    i++;
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

doesn't work... .

greetings

Comment: Are you sure that the track is in PLAYSTATE_PLAYING when you reach the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are playing a static track, use `getPlaybackHeadPosition()` and compare the returned value with the total number of samples (note, samples and not bytes - although their numbers could match) of your audio.

Answer (score -1):

Your call of `play()` should probably be in a background thread. Then your `getPlayState()` might get called. This is assuming `play()` is a blocking call, which it looks like.